# Run-time error '2467': The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I am running into a 2467 error after the following code ():

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub CmdReject_Click()
Dim lngID As Long

    lngID = Me.ID
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    DoCmd.Close , ""
    Beep 
    MsgBox "Issue has been saved.", vbInformation, ""
    NewFormIssue (lngID)

End Sub

Private Sub NewFormIssue(lngID As Long)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Frm_Issue_Entry", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
    Me.Person.Value = DLookup("[Previous_Person]","[tbl_Issue_Log]", "[ID] = " lngID)

End Sub
```

The run-time error occurs during the `Me.Person.Value = DLookup("[Person]","[tbl_Issue_Log]", "[ID] = " lngID)` line.

I am trying to use the ID of the previous form to populate 11 fields on this new form so the user doesn't have to redo everything using dlookup, which worked before but I can't seem to find why it just stopped working...

Comment: `"[ID] = " & lngID`

Comment: `Me` always refers to the object/instance where the current code is running - opening another form doesn't change that reference.

Comment: @HansUp, that produces the run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.  It isn't liking ```Me.```.  I was able to work around the issue by explicitly using ```Form_Frm_Issue_Entry.Person```.  the code closes the ```Frm_Issue_Entry``` form, and opens the same form with a new record.

Comment: @TimWilliams You are correct, my issue was using ```Me``` which was referring to the object that was closed. It still doesn't make sense to me why this had worked previously and now does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what was happening (at least from a high level standpoint).  The `Me` was still pointing to the previously closed form, not the new form added, causing the error.  I fixed the issue by using `Form_Frm_Issue_Entry.Person.Value` instead, but I am not sure why it worked previously.